# Inserindo dados duplicados em Array Javascript (push)

Tags: javascript

Encontrei um determinado problema em um trecho de código cujo o qual estava desenvolvendo. Desconfiado de que o problema poderia estar em alguma outra parte do projeto, resolvi criar um ambiente de teste menor (Com um outro cenário) para verificar se o erro ira persistir, Para minha surpresa, ele persistiu.

Então vamos a questão com base neste cenário reduzido. No código abaixo estou gerando duas variáveis globais `agendaA` e `agendaB`. O propósito destas variáveis é armazenar o nome de todos os elementos criados, relacionando um ao outro.

Exemplo:

- Se eu gerar o elemento **A**, a `agendaA` e a `agendaB` deverão estar representados por `agendaA[A] possuí []` e `agendaB[A] possuí []`.
- Agora se eu inserir um novo elemento com o nome **B** a representação deverá ser: `agendaA[A] possuí [B]`, `agendaA[B] possuí [A]`, `agendaB[A] possuí [B]` e `agendaB[B] possuí [A]`.
- E assim deverá prosseguir se eu adicionar um elemento **C**: `agendaA[A] possuí [B. C]`, `agendaA[B] possuí [A, C]`, `agendaA[C] possuí [A. B]` `agendaB[A] possuí [B, C]`, `agendaB[B] possuí [A, C]` e `agendaB[C] possuí [A. B]`.

Entretanto, a partir do momento em que o segundo elemento é criado o valor das agendas passa a ser duplicado. Ao invés de gerar um resultado `agendaA[A] possuí [B]` ele gera `agendaA[A] possuí [B, B]`.

O mais intrigante é que se eu comentar a linha `agendaA[elemento_selecionado].push(id_elemento);` ou a linha `agendaB[elemento_selecionado].push(id_elemento);` a aplicação funciona perfeitamente surgindo mais um mistério - Se eu comentei a linha `agendaA[elemento_selecionado].push(id_elemento);` como o valor esta sendo inserido na varivel `agendaA`?

Execute o código abaixo, insira alguns elementos e faça um debug das variáveis `agendaA` (console.log(agendaA)) e `agendaB` (console.log(agendaB)) e veja o resultado.

```js
agendaA = [];
agendaB = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  //Função de criação e registro de elementos.
  $('#inserir_elemento').click(function(){
    //Resgata o contúedo já gerado no DOM.
    var conteudo = document.getElementById('conteudo');

    //Resgato o nome do novo elemento a ser criado --- Variavel Global
    id_elemento = $('#nome').val();

    //Variavel que ira receber o nome do(s) elemento(s) já criado()s  --- Variavel Global
    elementos = [];

    //Percorre cada elemento já gerado para adicionar o nome do novo elemento na(s) respectiva(s) agenda(s).
    $('p').each(function(){
      //Recebe o nome do elemento selecionado.
      var elemento_selecionado = $(this).text();

      //Insere o nome do eleneto a ser criado na agenda do elemento selecionado pelo 'each'.
      agendaA[elemento_selecionado].push(id_elemento); //***Comente esta linha ou a debaixo e veja o resultado.
      agendaB[elemento_selecionado].push(id_elemento);

      elementos.push(elemento_selecionado);
    });

    //Cria um registro na agenda para o elemento a ser criado.
    agendaA[id_elemento] = elementos;
    agendaB[id_elemento] = elementos;

    //Cria um novo elemento.
    var novo_elemento  = document.createElement('p');

    //Insere as informações no elemento.
    novo_elemento.textContent = id_elemento;
    novo_elemento.className = id_elemento;

    //Insere o novo elemento no DOM.
    conteudo.appendChild(novo_elemento);

    //Limpa o valor do input 'nome'.
    $('#nome').val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <!-- Registra um novo usuário -->
  <input id="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome">
  <button id="inserir_elemento">Inserir</button>
</section>
<section>
  <div id="conteudo">
    <!-- Recebe o conteúdo gerado no Javascript -->
  </div>
</section>
```

Tente támbem comentas as linhas descritas no código (Uma de cada vez) e vejá o resultado através do debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema é simples, mas antes quero que olhe o seguinte trecho de codigo.:

```js
//define um unico array vazio.
var elementos = [];

$('p').each(function(){
  //obtem o valor selecionado.
  var elemento_selecionado = $(this).text();

  //como agendaA[id_elemento] e agendaB[id_elemento] apontam para o mesmo array.
  //então o elemento é inserido duas vezes no array.
  agendaA[elemento_selecionado].push(id_elemento);
  agendaB[elemento_selecionado].push(id_elemento);

  elementos.push(elemento_selecionado);
});

//agendaA[id_elemento] e agendaB[id_elemento] apontam para o mesmo array.
agendaA[id_elemento] = elementos;
agendaB[id_elemento] = elementos;
```

Ou seja, o seu problema é que `agendaA[n]` e `agendaB[n]` possuem uma referencia para o mesmo objeto.

Ainda assim o seu codigo poderia ser bem mais simples.

```js
agendaA = {}
agendaB = {}

var nome = document.getElementById("nome");
var inserirElemento = document.getElementById("inserir_elemento");
var removerElemento = document.getElementById("remover_elemento");
var conteudoA = document.getElementById("conteudoA");
var conteudoB = document.getElementById("conteudoB");

inserirElemento.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (nome.value && !agendaA[nome.value])
  {
    var keysA = Object.keys(agendaA);
    var keysB = Object.keys(agendaB);
    keysA.forEach(function (key, indice) {
      agendaA[key].push(nome.value);
    });
    keysB.forEach(function (key, indice) {
      agendaB[key].push(nome.value);
    });
    agendaA[nome.value] = keysA;
    agendaB[nome.value] = keysB;
    
    conteudoA.textContent = JSON.stringify(agendaA);
    conteudoB.textContent = JSON.stringify(agendaB);
  }
});

removerElemento.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (nome.value && agendaA[nome.value])
  {
    delete agendaA[nome.value];
    delete agendaB[nome.value];
    
    Object.keys(agendaA).forEach(function (key) {
      var elementos = agendaA[key];
      var indice = elementos.indexOf(nome.value);
      elementos.splice(indice, 1);
    });
    Object.keys(agendaB).forEach(function (key, indice) {
      var elementos = agendaB[key];
      var indice = elementos.indexOf(nome.value);
      elementos.splice(indice, 1);
    });
    
    conteudoA.textContent = JSON.stringify(agendaA);
    conteudoB.textContent = JSON.stringify(agendaB);
  }
});
```

```html
<section>
  <!-- Registra um novo usuário -->
  <input id="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome">
  <button id="inserir_elemento">Inserir</button>
  <button id="remover_elemento">Remover</button>
</section>
<section>
  <div>Agenda A: <span id="conteudoA"></span></div>
  <div>Agenda B: <span id="conteudoB"></span></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua ajuda. ; )